# Error with Spring ldap pooling

Tags: spring-data, spring-ldap

i build async jersey web services, and now i need to make some operations with ldap.
I have configure Spring beam.xml in this mode:

```
<bean id="contextSourceTarget" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
        <property name="url" value="${ldap.url}" />
        <property name="base" value="${ldap.base}" />
        <property name="userDn" value="${ldap.userDn}" />
        <property name="password" value="${ldap.password}" />
        <property name="pooled" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="contextSource"
        class="org.springframework.ldap.pool.factory.PoolingContextSource">
        <property name="contextSource" ref="contextSourceTarget" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
    </bean>   

    <bean id="ldapTreeBuilder" class="com.me.ldap.LdapTreeBuilder">
        <constructor-arg ref="ldapTemplate" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="personDao" class="com.me.ldap.PersonDaoImpl">
        <property name="ldapTemplate" ref="ldapTemplate" />
    </bean>
```

But when i try to use ldap i have this error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'contextSource' defined in class path resource [config/Beans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/KeyedPoolableObjectFactory
```

In my project i have commons-pool2-2.2.jar lib, but still i have this error..i try to add commons-pool2-2.2.jar in TOMCAT_PATH/lib but not works..

***UPDATE:***

If i put commons-pool-1.6.jar it works.. but if i want to use pool2 how i can do? only i must change class inn commons-pool2-2.2.jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

Since at least Spring LDAP 2.3.2 you can now use commons-pool2. Spring LDAP now provides two classes:

For commons-pool 1.x:
`org.springframework.ldap.pool.factory.PoolingContextSource`

For commons-pool 2.x:
`org.springframework.ldap.pool2.factory.PooledContextSource`

Details can be found here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/issues/351#issuecomment-586551591

**Original Answer:**

Unfortunately Spring-Ldap uses commons-pool and not commons-pool2. As you have found the class `org.apache.commons.pool.KeyedPoolableObjectFactory` does not exist in commons-pool2 (it has a different package structure), hence the error.

There is a Jira issue for the Spring-ldap project asking them to upgrade/support commons-pool2:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/LDAP-316

Until that has been completed you will have to use commons-pool 1.6.

Comment: commons-pool2 is now supported

Comment: I am using Spring Boot 2.4.1 with spring-security-ldap and commons-pool v1.6 is still needed.

Comment: @Avec, this comment in the spring-ldap Jira Issue details what you need to do to use commons-pool2: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/issues/351#issuecomment-586551591